Vite is building 3rd party css after my app's main css. How to ensure that doesn't happen and my css is alway the last?
This is my pre-built app.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>ABC</title>
    <script type="module" src="./src/app/theme.ts"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/app/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


This is my post-built app.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>ABC</title>
    
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/app-8dd6a65e.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/browser-polyfill-bde3c9b4.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/base-8ec43b63.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/base-1f0c8050.css"> //<-- I want this to be the last
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/app-858b812a.css"> //<-- This is a 3P library's whose style I need to override in `base-1f0c8050.css`
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>

sidepanel.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <script type="module" src="./src/app/theme.ts"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #app {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>


main.tsx:
import { RouterProvider } from '@tanstack/react-router'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { router } from './router'
import './i18n'
import './base.scss'

const container = document.getElementById('app')!
const root = createRoot(container)
root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />)


router.tsx:
declare module '@tanstack/react-router' {
  interface Register {
    router: typeof router
  }
}
export { router }


theme.ts:
export enum ThemeMode {
  Auto = 'auto',
  Light = 'light',
  Dark = 'dark',
}

function getUserThemeMode(): ThemeMode {
  return (localStorage.getItem('themeMode') as ThemeMode) || ThemeMode.Auto
}
applyThemeMode(getUserThemeMode())

export {}


vite.config.ts:
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import { viteZip } from 'vite-plugin-zip-file';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), react(),
    viteZip({
      folderPath: path.resolve('./dist'),
      outPath: path.resolve('./zips'),
      zipName: 'chromium.zip',
    })
  ],
  esbuild: {
    keepNames: true,
  },
  build: {
    minify: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: [path.resolve('./app.html'), path.resolve('./sidepanel.html')],
    },
  },
})

package.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@crxjs/vite-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "@headlessui/tailwindcss": "^0.1.3",
    "@parcel/config-webextension": "^2.10.3",
    "@parcel/optimizer-data-url": "^2.11.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-inline-string": "^2.11.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-graphql": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.253",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@types/react-scroll-to-bottom": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/turndown": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/webextension-polyfill": "^0.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "daisyui": "^4.4.10",
    "eslint": "^8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "parcel": "^2.9.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^11.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.0.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.5.2",
    "vite-plugin-zip-file": "^2.0.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/css": "^11.11.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@floating-ui/react": "^0.24.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@radix-ui/colors": "^0.1.8",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.6",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^7.54.0",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.54.0",
    "@tanstack/react-router": "0.0.1-beta.83",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "browser-fs-access": "^0.34.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "eventsource-parser": "^1.0.0",
    "expiry-map": "^2.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
    "github-markdown-css": "^5.2.0",
    "gpt3-tokenizer": "^1.1.5",
    "highlight.js": "^11.8.0",
    "http-proxy-agent": "^6.0.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.1",
    "i18next": "^23.7.6",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.2",
    "immer": "^10.0.2",
    "inter-ui": "^3.19.3",
    "jotai": "^2.2.1",
    "jotai-immer": "^0.2.0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.5",
    "langchain": "^0.0.175",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "lucide-react": "^0.223.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "ofetch": "^1.0.1",
    "plausible-tracker": "^0.3.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-ga4": "^2.1.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-i18next": "^12.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "react-node-to-string": "^0.1.1",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^4.2.0",
    "react-select-search": "^4.1.7",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.4.1",
    "react-viewport-list": "^7.1.1",
    "react-wrap-balancer": "^1.0.0",
    "rehype-highlight": "^6.0.0",
    "rehype-katex": "^7.0.0",
    "rehype-sanitize": "^5.0.1",
    "rehype-stringify": "^9.0.3",
    "remark-breaks": "^3.0.3",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "remark-math": "^5.1.1",
    "remark-parse": "^10.0.2",
    "remark-rehype": "^10.1.0",
    "remark-supersub": "^1.0.0",
    "swr": "^2.1.5",
    "tls-client": "^0.0.3",
    "turndown": "^7.1.2",
    "unified": "^10.1.2",
    "use-immer": "^0.9.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "webextension-polyfill": "^0.10.0",
    "websocket-as-promised": "^2.0.1",
    "zustand": "^4.3.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.15.0 <17.0.0",
    "npm": ">=8.19.4 <9.0.0"
  }
}


tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "manifest.config.ts"]
}


CLI command to trigger building is npm run build
How to make sure that no 3rd part css is after my main app's css and overriding it ?

@jsejcksn I added more details , if you are still struggling to understand the question let me know

The question still lacks a [mre]. Can you create one and edit the question to include it?

@jsejcksn Well I am not sure I know how to use vite building in MRE. do you know of any vite+react starter MRE ? Maybe if you can share one I can learn from it and then I can edit that code to include mine. None of the vite question on stackoverflow that I came across has any MRE either to learn from.

^ A [mre] for a Node.js project should include the contents of every file (except what's in node_modules). It should also include the versions used for Node.js, npm, etc., and all of the CLI commands involved. It needs to include all of the information necessary for someone on this site to reproduce the scenario you encounter. See the link for more info.

@jsejcksn not sure that link has any starter code for vite. Sharing the same link for all questions isn't that helpful. Anyways I added the package,json and tsconfig.json as you reqested. Rest of the files were already shown earlier. And the only CLI command to trigger vite building is npm run build. Hopefully now you can reproduce.

^ I still see import specifier references to local files that aren’t shown in the question. Also, is this really a minimal example?

@jsejcksn the link you pasted doesn't have any starter code for vite for MSE, in fact it is the same link as the first one. I dont know wheather it is MSE or not, I gave you all the files that you asked for. Let me know what is still blocking you from reproducing, despite getting all things you asked for . so you want to see manifest.config.ts? is that what is blocking you to reproduce ?

@jsejcksn None of the posts I came across tagged with vite  have anything starter code for MSE. Had there been one, I wouldn't asked for a starter code for vite as example.
